# Customizing a room in Exchange

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I am very new to EWS... I would like to set properties on a room that I can later access.

I looked into `ExtendedProperties`, but these are only available to objects that inherit from `Item`, but since a room is just an email address, it does not inherit from `Item`.

I also looked at the "Custom Attributes" under Recipients > Resources > General > More options but these attributes are not exposed via EWS.

Is there any way I can set properties that I can tie to a room and later access them via EWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Room is Mailbox and a Mailbox has folders so you can do one of two things

Create you own custom Extended properties and set them on one of the Folders in the Mailbox (eg the Inbox or Calendar Folder)

Create a Folder Associated Item (FAI Items) these are hidden items in Folder that are designed to holder configuration information. (eg there is a FAI that holds the configuration of the room etc eg http://gsexdev.blogspot.com.au/2015/12/showing-calendar-configuration-of.html

One last thing you can do is create a MailTip for the Room Mailbox and you can then access that MailTip using EWS.